# PHP MySql Picture Data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I cannot display an image from my Mysql Database.
I've kept following all the examples and other posts but can't seem to get it right...

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MyDatabase;charset=utf8mb4', 'tester', '1234567890');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$request = "347";
$mytable = "u55";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$mytable." WHERE Id = :SearchName ");
$stmt->bindParam(':SearchName', $request, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $result[0]['TheAvatar'];
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo '<img src="'.$result.'" />';
?>
```

My error that I have is image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
The only difference I have from the examples is the data is stored in TEXT not BLOB/VARCHAR..
I've also tried using BinToHex() with the data to see if that made a difference.
The pictures come from a phone and are stored on a server.

The Pic data is in this link below (cant copy paste it so..)
http://spyon.agency/PicData.bmp

EDIT:

This is the code that stores the data into the DB..
It's a code snippet from the main file, the login remains the same as posted above. The Data comes from a JSON string.

```
$MessageDecoded = base64_decode ($request);
$input = json_decode($MessageDecoded);
```

Then the function that stores the data is

```
        $mTheAvatar = $input[$i]->TheAvatar;
        $mTheDirection= $input[$i]->TheDirection;
        $mTheGroup = $input[$i]->TheGroup;
        $mTheMedia = $input[$i]->TheMedia;
        $mTheMessage = $input[$i]->TheMessage;
        $mTheSenderName= $input[$i]->TheSenderName;
        $mTheThumbImage = $input[$i]->TheThumbImage;
        $mTheTime = $input[$i]->TheTime;
        $mTheMediaExtension = $input[$i]->TheMediaExtension;
        $statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$mDevice.' '.
        '(TheAvatar , TheDirection , TheGroup , TheMedia , TheMediaExtension , TheMessage , TheSenderName , TheThumbImage , TheTime) '.
        'VALUES (:aTheAvatar, :aTheDirection, :aTheGroup , :aTheMedia, :aTheMediaExtension , :aTheMessage, :aTheSenderName, :aTheThumbImage, :aTheTime)');
        try {
            $statement->execute(array(
            "aTheAvatar" => $mTheAvatar,
            "aTheDirection" => $mTheDirection,
            "aTheGroup" => $mTheGroup,
            "aTheMedia" => $mTheMedia,
            "aTheMediaExtension" => $mTheMediaExtension,
            "aTheMessage" => $mTheMessage,
            "aTheSenderName" => $mTheSenderName,
            "aTheThumbImage" => $mTheThumbImage,
            "aTheTime" => $mTheTime
            ));
        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            echo "An Error occured!"; 
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            die;
        }
```

Comment: your are overwrite the result object after assigning image.

Comment: could you tried echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result).'" />';

Comment: It would be useful to know how you stored the image onto the database. Can you show that code as well please. Its most likely you did that incorrectly

Comment: You cannot store binary data in a TEXT column and expect to get it all back in one piece. Try converting the image using `$mTheAvatar = base64_encode($input[$i]->TheAvatar);` and then `base64_decode()` it on retrieval from the database

Comment: encode before insert. decode on retrieval before sending to the browser

Comment: I think the problem actually goes all the way back to the app sending the data then .. it's not being sent properly, then I'm storing it in text (next error) .. so will have to fault test from the beginning of the process.

Comment: The app is sending the exact string I'm getting so its sending converted binary to string which is probably the problem

Comment: life would have been a lot lot easier if you had saved the image in the filesystem and merely it's name in the database like you are supposed to

Comment: Slightly .. the pic still has to get to you before saving it as a "Pic" so you still dealing with data string ..

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly The problem stemmed from the app itself, the rest didn't need modifying and all fell into place except I decoded from base64 when reading the data from DB

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to show your image :

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result ).'"/>';
```

Comment: can you add code that you store image into database?

Comment: Its a bit late trying to use `base64_encode()`  if that data retrieved is already corrupted by incorrect insertion